# Dropping a constraint in sybase ASE [Cannot drop the constraint]

Tags: database, sybase, sybase-ase15

I want to drop constraint of a column, like this,

```
alter table dbo.menu_items 
drop constraint FK_menu_items_menu_icons
```

but I am getting an error,

SQL Error [3701] [42S02]: Cannot drop the constraint 'FK_menu_items_menu_icons', because it doesn't exist in the system catalogs.

When I checked on `menu_items` table, in `Properties`, `Foreign Keys`, clearly there is `FK_menu_items_menu_icons`

Please help how can I fix this ?

Comment: please update the question with the complete output from `sp_helpconstraint 'dbo.menu_items'`

Comment: @markp-fuso problem solved, i posted an answer for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, here's the raw SQL query that works:

```
alter table dbo.menu_items 
drop constraint fk_menu_icons
```